Can I set JBOD and RAID10 at the same time on the NAS?
I am looking to buy ASUSTOR's FS6712X NAS, and 12 of 2TB NVME SSD and now have a question about the RAID settings.
Is it possible to set JBOD and RAID10 at the same time? So like having 12TB capacity of drive just show up on the computer and use it like just a one drive, with having RAID setted up so it has backup on RAIDed drives.
I assume it can "technically" be done, but I was not able to find anything about this.
Or if there is other recommendation, or if there is something I am wrong about, I would like to know about it.

"Is it possible to set JBOD and RAID10 at the same time?"- No

Can you help us understand why you would want what you're asking for? What performance problem are you trying to solve, or what risk of data loss are you trying to prevent? I'm having a hard time imagining what problem you're trying to solve with your proposed setup that wouldn't be solved better by RAID 6.

You cant have redundancy and maintain access to the full 12TB of storage. The Flextor does support JBOD and allows you to group the 6 drives together as one big storage volume. You can then use FTP/SMB/iSCSI/... to expose the entire volume or parts of it. All other forms of RAID will introduce redundancy at the cost of storage.

For different arrays of disks, if the NAS supports it, yes, but for the same array? No.
JBOD is one method of arranging the drives in an array, and RAID is another. They are not the same thing, even if they may share certain principles.
Some (probably many or even most) NAS devices support multiple arrays, because there can be good reasons to have different arrays with different characteristics. And if they do support multiple arrays, it is usually also the case that you can define the array type (JBOD, RAID level, etc) for each array separately from the other arrays in the NAS.
